# Cannot properly search in PHP MYSQL

Tags: mysql, search

I developed a search engine using pure **PHP and MYSQL**, and the problem is when I enter a keyword in the search engine, if the search results are available for that keyword in the database, the search results are **first** displaying results which contain that searched keyword at the end in the search results values, but I when I enter a search keyword, I expect the search results to first display the exactly matched (equal) search results values based on the search keyword I have searched, and then other related keyword values (like at the end, containing the searched keyword). Please help me.

Below is the query

```
$joojbe_1 = 'some text';

SELECT *, MATCH(title,description,keywords,website) AGAINST ('%".$joojbe_1."%') AS score FROM search WHERE MATCH(title,description,keywords,website) AGAINST ('%".$joojbe_1."%') ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the documentation mentions,

> When MATCH() is used in a WHERE clause, the rows returned are
>   automatically sorted with the highest relevance first.

So, like @dionei says, removing the 'DESC' would solve your issue.

Also, I guess the order by score is unnecessary too.

Comment: i change and run it, but no change output result.